# Anime about a group of kids with special abilities who go to school together

Tags: story-identification, anime

From what I remember there are kids with special abilities who go to school with each other. Some are not as strong and leave, which is part of the mystery. I think there are some human-like monsters that the kids help, and as the kids grow up, the human-like monsters build an army.

I remember that at the end there is a couple who grew up among the kids who fight one of their old friends who was thought to be dead.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Please have a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) for tips about using the site, including hints about story identification questions which may jog your memory.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds very similar to **Shin Sekai Yori (From the New World)**

> Set in Japan, 1000 years after the modern era, Shin Sekai Yori follows
> the life of Saki Watanabe, a girl from the town of Kamisu 66. In this
> age, **all humans possess powerful psychic abilities**, and live an
> idyllic life in agrarian villages. Saki gains her special powers at the age of
> twelve and joins her friends Satoru Asahina, Maria Akizuki, Mamoru
> Itou, Shun Aonuma, and Reiko Amano in enrolling at school to hone her
> gifts.
>
> Two years later, as Saki and her friends reach
> adolescence and develop relationships, Shun starts to **distance
> himself from the others and eventually goes missing**.
>
> **Yakomaru's colony slowly ascends to power while conquering other colonies** and wiping out the Giant Hornet colony, eventually
> attacking Kamisu 66 with what is believed to be an Ogre that the
> Monster Rats refer to as their "Messiah."

All the parts match including the human-like monsters building an army.

Very good show with all the build up to the surprising twist at the end!